# How to convert string to boolean condition in java/android?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am working on a survey application and getting data from server. I am facing problem in converting String to Boolean conditions, which is in String format.
here is the conditions. I have searched a lot on web but found no solution.
I have read some post related to it, but no help.

http://www.java-examples.com/convert-java-string-object-boolean-object
http://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/convert-string-to-boolean-primitive-in-java/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/boolean_parseboolean.htm

```
String s = "{hidSection=if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\"))\n" +
            "    ,1,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")||\n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\"))\n" +
            "    ,2,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\"))\n" +
            "    ,3,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\"))\n" +
            "    ,4,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")||                (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\"))\n" +
            "    ,5,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")||                \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\"))\n" +
            "    ,6,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\"))\n" +
            "    ,7,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\") || \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\"))\n" +
            "    ,8,\"\"))))))))}";
```

i followed the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538755/how-to-convert-string-object-to-boolean-object). But did not help me. How to convert string to Boolean condition?

Comment: Sorry I am not following you. Could You write more clearly?

Comment: ok... i have three question.. Q4a, Q4b,Q4c.
now according to the answers of Q4a and Q4b, i need to auto answer the Q4c.

Comment: and the answer should be based on conditions given in my question.

Comment: Q4a.NAOK means "answer of Q4a" like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning code from server is terrible awful. Anyways, this code I give you do some steps:

1. removes new lines and multispaces into one length space from input.
2. finds words by pattern where word starts with `if` and ends with digits. Adds them to array.
3. prepares pattern with user chosen options combining into similar to `(Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")` (answer 1 and answer2).
4. checking if array contains word like in point 3. If found, retains word from array and split by comma. Second word from splitting is the answer.

---

```
private void doStuff() {
    int answer1 = 2;
    int answer2 = 1;

    String s = "{hidSection=if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\"))\n" +
            "    ,1,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")||\n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\"))\n" +
            "    ,2,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"7\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"12\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\"))\n" +
            "    ,3,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\"))\n" +
            "    ,4,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")||                (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"6\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"11\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\"))\n" +
            "    ,5,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"4\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"5\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"6\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"7\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"4\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"5\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")|| \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"8\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\")||                \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"9\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\")|| (Q4a.NAOK==\"10\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\"))\n" +
            "    ,6,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"3\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\"))\n" +
            "    ,7,if(((Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"1\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"2\") || (Q4a.NAOK==\"2\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\") || \n" +
            "            (Q4a.NAOK==\"3\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"1\"))\n" +
            "    ,8,\"\"))))))))}";

    String answer = getAnswer(answer1, answer2, s);
    Log.d("xxx", "answer:" + answer);
}

private String getAnswer(int answer1, int answer2, String s) {
    //remove spaces 2 or more length and replace to 1
    s = s.replaceAll("\n", "");
    s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

    ArrayList<String> states = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("if\\({3}.*?\\,\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        states.add(m.group());
    }

    String stateFormat = "Q4a.NAOK==\"%d\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"%d\"";
    String stateFormatted = String.format(stateFormat, answer1, answer2);

    for (int i = 0; i < states.size(); i++) {
        if (states.get(i).contains(stateFormatted)) {
            String[] items = states.get(i).split(",");
            if (items.length > 1) {
                return items[1].trim();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;//or null or integer -1
}
```

Comment: Hey... You are a life saver ... Bro :)

Comment: how can i use the code without hard code question name.

`String stateFormat = "Q4a.NAOK==\"%d\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"%d\"";`

Comment: I still dont follow your question. Using StringFormat in string where `%d` you put digit.

Comment: actually you did it hard coded like `"Q4a.NAOK==\"%d\" ` .
Can you tell me how can i find the questions used in conditions string ?
I mean i have no idea which question's answer i will get in conditions..

Comment: at the beginning of my code I declared user's two answers in variables `int answer1 = 2; int answer2 = 1;` They are used in that `"Q4a.NAOK==\"%d\" && Q4b.NAOK==\"%d\""` by puttin answer1 and answer2 to `%d`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: bro is there any way,that i can get all occurrence of all strings before the `.NAOK` like : `Q4a.NAOK` and i could get `Q4a`.