# get total hours from two timepicker

Tags: java, android, timepicker

Can someone tell me how can I get the total hours from two TimePicker ?It is possible to get since the two timepicker are actually getting from the same function.

**WorkDetails.java**

```
        EditText TimeIn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        EditText TimeOut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        TimeIn.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    TimePick time = new TimePick(v);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    time.show(ft, "TimePicker");
                }
            }
        });


        TimeOut.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v,boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    TimePick time = new TimePick(v);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    time.show(ft, "TimePicker");

                }
            }
        });
```

**TimePick.java**

```
public class TimePick extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
   EditText time;

    public TimePick(View view)
    {
       time=(EditText)view;
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,hour,minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourofDay, int minute)
    {

        time.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
    }


}
```

**workdetails.xml**

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_x="147dp"
        android:layout_y="170dp"
        android:hint="Select Time"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Time In"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_x="23dp"
        android:layout_y="184dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Time out"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_x="23dp"
        android:layout_y="247dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_x="147dp"
        android:layout_y="241dp"
        android:hint="Select Time"/>
```

Comment: concat your hour and minutes with (.) >> convert them to float >> perform the calculation..
Note.. time should be in 24 hr format.

Comment: can you explain more ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can calculate the hours of the day to do a concat your time hours and min with (.) dot >> later parse it as a float >> and make a differance. here is a working code snippet.

```
        float end = Float.parseFloat("21.00");
        float start = Float.parseFloat("10.00");

        System.out.println(end-start);
```

change you method like:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourofDay, int minute)
    {

        time.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + "." + Integer.toString(minute));
    }
```

and get the value later from `editText.gettext();`

**Edit:**

Make your `TimeIn` editText variable static and get the value of it while setting timeout like this..

```
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourofDay, int minute)
        {

            time.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + "." + Integer.toString(minute));

          if(time.getId==R.id.editText7){
            if(YourActivity.TimeIn !=null){
            String timeIn = YourActivity.TimeIn.getText().toString();

            float end = Float.parseFloat(time.getText().toString);
            float start = Float.parseFloat(timeIn);

            System.out.println(end-start);
           // do what you need with your calculated hours
         }
        }
        }
```

Comment: But how can I get the end and start value since they are in  the same function(onTimeSet)?

Comment: where you want to calculate it... on some button click ?

Comment: I want it to be automatic..After user select time in and time out, it will display the total hours

Comment: Let's say I get a value for time in and another value for time out. How can I pass them into one function ?

Comment: than make the `EditText TimeIn` static in `YourActivity` and get the value of `TimeIn` in `onTimeSet()` while you are setting it for `TimeOut`...
see the edits..

Comment: Thanks for your help. Highly appreciated :)

Comment: pleasure to help... happy coding... :)

Comment: @Hoo can you plz.. u pvote my question here... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694455/how-to-convert-string-to-boolean-condition-in-java-android]… .. actually i m unable to ask anymore question due to too much downvoting of my question..

Comment: thnk u so much... bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Switch and Case using Timepicker Id

```
     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourofDay, int minute)
                {
                  int start,end,remains;
                  switch(view.getId()){
                       case R.id.editText6: 
                                   time.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                                   start=hourofDay;
                                   break;
                       case R.id.editText7: 
                                   time.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                                   end=hourofDay;
                                   break;
                                    }
                        //Use can declare remains globlally and use where you want
                         remain=end-start;

                 }
```

Comment: How can I get the total hours from editText6 and editText 7?

Comment: Use `Timepicker` in the layout instead of `EditText` and intialize in the activtiy