# How to mention Boolean value in 'Examples' in feature file of cucumber and make sure it creates a method in java?

Tags: java, cucumber

I am trying a negative scenario for susbcription name(string) for different data type which is boolean.
Examples:

```
|Subscription Name|Ext Id|Owner Firstname|Owner Lastname|

|true             |"423" |"abc"          |"xyz"         |
```

Comment: what exactly your problem is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I never put quotes around items in the examples table. I put quotes around the item in the step definition.

```
When I search for "<Ext Id>"
```

As for the Subscription name element, you can convert that within your step definition using [How to convert String object to Boolean Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538755/how-to-convert-string-object-to-boolean-object)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) .I did the same for converting String to Boolean.                                                                                             boolean boolean2 = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");