# Convert String to boolean only if input is "true" or "false"

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, boolean

How can I make sure that the input of a String is either "true" or "false" and then parse it to a boolean?

For example:

```
String input = "true"; -> boolean result = true;
String input = "false"; -> boolean result = false;
String input = "foobar"; -> throw new InvalidInputException("true or false is allowed");
```

Comment: Check it with an `if` statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert String object to Boolean Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538755/how-to-convert-string-object-to-boolean-object)

Comment: you mean: how does equals or equalsIgnoreCase works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try some thing like this :

```
String s = input.toLowerCase();
Boolean b ;
if ("true".equals(s) || "false".equals(s)) {
   b= Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
}
else  {
    throw new InvalidInputException("true or false is allowed");
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! `toLowerCase()` isn't needed though, right?

Comment: You either use it this way or use: `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: up to 3 times `toLowerCase` [: -|  // and `<constant>.equals(...` (just my *feeling*) [: -(

Comment: @user85421 ye could be refactored

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to do `if else` statements if you want to make absolutely sure that the input is either "true"/"TRUE" or "false"/"FALSE":

```
if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(input) {
    return true;
} else if ("false".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
    return false;
} else {
    throw new InvalidInputException("true or false is allowed")
}
```

If you literally only want the case sensitive "true" or "false" then change `.equalsIgnoreCase()` to `.equals()`

Alternatively you can use `BooleanUtils` in Apache Commons Lang
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html

```
 Boolean bool = BooleanUtils.toBooleanObject(input)
```

If it's neither "true" or "false" (Amongst other things like "t", "y", "yes" etc - see JavaDoc) then `null` is returned

Comment: If you switched the order of the string compare to `"true".equalsIgnoreCase(input)` you wouldn't need those null checks.

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase() is not case-sensitive, right? So "TRUE" would also work.

Comment: Yes but I assumed "true" and "TRUE" would want to be treated the same. Will edit to make clear

Answer (score 1):

From java doc about method [Boolean.valueOf(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-):

> Returns a Boolean with a value represented by the specified string.
>   The Boolean returned represents a true value if the string argument is
>   not null and is equal, ignoring case, to the string "true".

So you can use it in this way:

```
public static String getBoolean(String s) {
    if (!s.equals("true") && !s.equals("false")) {
            throw new InvalidInputException("true or false is allowed");
    }
    return Boolean.valueOf(s) ? "true": "false";
}
```

Comment: you understand that you will throw an Exception for valid input as well, right?

Comment: @Stultuske, probably mine is dumb question, if you have some time could you give me an example of valid input raising an exception ? At the moment I cannot figure it.

Comment: you're on the right track, but the comment you state says it yourself: Boolean.valueOf ignores cases, the tests you perform before you call Boolean.valueOf don't, so in your example: getBoolean for value "True" will throw an Exception, while it should return true.

Comment: @Stultuske, then I misunderstood the question because I thought "True" is not a valid input but the only valid inputs are strings "true" and "false". If this is the case I delete my answer.

Comment: why delete? the answer isn't bad, and it provides a citation (plus link) to the relevant documentation. for a boolean, true and false are the only valid ones, for a Boolean on the other hand, that's not the case.

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for your help and time, I will follow your advice and I will not delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more modern (requires `--enable-preview` option to compile/run):

```java
var result = switch (input) {
    case "true"  -> true;
    case "false" -> false;
    default      -> throw new InvalidInputException ("true or false is allowed");
};
```

for case insensitive convertion:

```java
var result = switch (input.toLowerCase()) {
    case "true"  -> true;
    case "false" -> false;
    default      -> throw new InvalidInputException ("true or false is allowed");
};
```

<sub>Note: eventually missing check for `null`</sub>

Comment: kind of similar to the text posted as *code* (end of question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```java
if(input.toLowerCase().equals("true") || input.toLowerCase().equals("false")) {
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(input);
} else {
    throw new InvalidInputException("true or false is allowed");
}
```

Comment: But `Boolean.parseBoolean("foobar");` doesn't throw an Exception.